# jqplot piecharts Error issues

Tags: jquery, html, jqplot

I am using jqplot for making pie charts , I have used the sample code given in jqplot documentation but I am getting some errors like e.jqplot is undefined , my code is follows

```
      <script src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src='jquery.jqplot.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqplot.pieRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqplot.donutRenderer.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var data = [
        ['Heavy Industry', 12],['Retail', 9], ['Light Industry', 14],
        ['Out of home', 16],['Commuting', 7], ['Orientation', 9]
      ];
      var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot ('weeklyProjectSummary', [data],
        {
          seriesDefaults: {
            // Make this a pie chart.
            renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
              // Put data labels on the pie slices.
              // By default, labels show the percentage of the slice.
              showDataLabels: true
            }
          },
          //legend: { show:true, location: 'e' }
        }
      );
    });
    </script>


    <div id="weeklyProjectSummary"></div>
```

Comment: did the answer below work?? Or you still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting this error because you have not included the jqplot files properly.

Make sure you have copied the `jquery.jqplot.js`, `jqplot.pieRenderer.min.js`, `jqplot.donutRenderer.min.js` in the code folder.

According to me you have copied the `jquery.jqplot.min.js` file in the folder.
And you are including the `jquery.jqplot.js` file in the HTML code

Check it once. If you have copy-pasted the minified file(.min) in the folder, then correct it in the html `<script>` tag.
Change to : `<script type="text/javascript" src='jquery.jqplot.min.js'></script>` (add '.min')

Regards,
Anish